# Have user select file name from commandline option menu

Tags: powershell, user-input, optionmenu

I want a script that asks the user to select from a list option, like:

```
Please select a kind of report

1.HeadOffice 
2.All offices
3.Office1
4.Office2
5.Office3
```

Code:

```powershell
$headoffice = headoffice.csv 
$Alloffices = alloffices.csv
$Office1 = office1.csv
$Office2 = office2.csv
$Office3 = office3.csv

$csv = "selected one"

Foreach($target in $csv){

    # Do custom scan AND rainbows.
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should create a [hashtable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) where the file names are numbered like so:

```powershell
$table = @{
    '1' = 'headoffice.csv'
    '2' = 'alloffices.csv'
    '3' = 'office1.csv'
    '4' = 'office2.csv'
    '5' = 'office3.csv'
}
```

Next, you can ask the user to select an option using [`Read-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) and a [here-string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```powershell
$choice = Read-Host @'
Please select a kind of report

1.HeadOffice 
2.All offices
3.Office1
4.Office2
5.Office3
'@
```

Finally, you can index the hashtable with that value and thereby access the appropriate file name:

```powershell
$filename = $table[$choice]
```

---

Note that if you are working with CSV files, you might also want to read up on [`Import-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx).